# Can't connect to Google Sheet via API (error 400)

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api

I am trying to display data from a error 400. The sheet is open to view, and the API should be properly configured. (ATM it has no restrictions.)

Sheet in question: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19T0BR78jzK6Z7WscK7X64oYe2DgxyFhv8TczRQSqClw/edit?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Sheet Connection</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Sheet Connection</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // The ID of your Google Sheet
      var sheetId = "19T0BR78jzK6Z7WscK7X64oYe2DgxyFhv8TczRQSqClw";

      // The range of the sheet that you want to retrieve data from
      var sheetRange = "Sheet1!A:D";

      // The API endpoint for retrieving data from a Google Sheet
      var apiUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + sheetId + "/values/" + sheetRange + "?key=YAIzaSyDj1DTIFTV-MLiWODZcavwKG51GHEttiPE";

      // Use jQuery to make an AJAX request to the Google Sheets API
      $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? What steps are you following to test this script and are you able to retrieve the information by just making the HTTP request `"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + sheetId + "/values/" + sheetRange + "?key=APIkey"`

Comment: @LorenaGomez If I run it like that then it works https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/19T0BR78jzK6Z7WscK7X64oYe2DgxyFhv8TczRQSqClw/values/Sheet1!A:D?key=AIzaSyDj1DTIFTV-MLiWODZcavwKG51GHEttiPE

But the script still does not for some reason.

Comment: How are you testing the script? Is this a published Google Apps Script as a public web app? What is the complete error that you get? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I think that your showing script works. From `But the script still does not for some reason.`, can you confirm the following points? 1. Your Spreadsheet is publicly shared. 2. Your API key is a valid key for retrieving the values from the Spreadsheet using Sheets API. 3. Your Spreadsheet ID and range are valid values? When these points are correct, I think that your showing script works.